# How to reorder using data from another object

Tags: javascript, vue.js

### Want to achieve

Vue 2.6.10

Thankyou for watching.
I am creating an application in Vue.js.
Please tell me about sorting array data.

An object called shops_masters contains this data.
[image]

On the other hand,The data item.shops contains only the name of the shop data associated with the item, as shown below)

```
[c_shop,b_shop]
```

I want to sort the data in this item.shops in ascending order of the order_number of shops_masters, but I can't think of a way to do it.

I hope you can tell me about this one.

Comment: So do you expect the result to be `[b_shop, c_shop]` ?

Comment: Hi!  Please post code, not a huge screenshot of the data structure. You can use a [computed](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/computed.html) value which returns the sorted array. How to sort array based on its contents can also be researched here. Please show some code of your attempt. [How much research is expected of you](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you wanna do is to create a map from entries like so:

```
const shopsMap = new Map(
  shops_masters.map(({ name, order_number }) => [name, order_number])
);
```

Then use it inside the `sort` method this way:

```
const sortedItemShops = item.shops.sort(
  (prev, next) => shopsMap.get(prev) - shopsMap.get(next)
);
```